# Auto collapse push navigation when clicking on the body using a AngularJs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating this push navigation using a directive with AngularJS, I know this components is very common but I didn't want to use a plugin, when user clicks/toggles the nav button, this animates the menu container along with the body and adds/remove 'is-open' class to body.

The question is how can I check for when the push menu/body are open and add a click event to auto collapse the push menu? I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/0ofvv7ok/)

and this is my directive:

```
angular.module('creativestudioApp')
      .directive('pushNav', function() {
          return {
              restrict: 'EA',
              link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                  element.on('click', function(event) {

                      element.toggleClass('is-open');

                      if (element.hasClass('is-open')) {

                          console.log('is-open');

                          $('body').addClass('is-open');
                          $('body').animate({
                              right: "184"
                          }, 200);
                          $('.push-nav').animate({
                              right: "0"
                          }, 200);

                          console.log('has class');

                      } else {
                          console.log('is-close');

                          $('body').removeClass('is-open');
                          $('body').animate({
                              right: "0"
                          }, 200);
                          $('.push-nav').animate({
                              right: "-184"
                          }, 200);
                      }

                  });
              }
          };
      });
```

Comment: The link for jsfiddle is not working. Could you update it?

Comment: @Ali My bad, I updated the jsfiddle

Comment: is this what you wanted - https://jsfiddle.net/nirus/f82shjn4/